# Posting 3 images using Stack Exchange's mobile app will result in the image order being destroyed

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, mobile-app

I have run into this bug several times now and I can replicate it easily across all devices.
If I post 3 images using the image tool on any of the mobile app platforms, the first tag always changes what image it is supposed to display. Since that's hard to explain, I took 3 random images and attached them to this question. Then, took a screenshot of before.

> [image]

Hit preview... And chaos erupts. The first image always changes to a different number than it should be.

> [image]

I've replicated this on both Android and iOS.

Comment: @AndrewT. Sort of. It's the same behavior, but it is happening under a different situation. It now only occurs once the markup has been previewed or posted. The supposive duplicate happens immedietly.